# install wordpress in blog folder + laravel in root folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I installed **laravel framework in root** folder, and **wordpress CMS in Blog folder**

Laravel Works well, **But WordPress does not work**

I redirect no-www to www and http to https in laravel `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

mysite url: https://www.zanborasal.com

wordpress blog folder : https://www.zanborasal.com/blog

Do you have any idea how can I correct my Wordp=Press installation?

Answer (score 1):

Just after `RewriteEngine On` if you add:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(wordpress-folder)
```

That will exclude your Wordpress install and let you have your own htaccess settings within the `wordpress-folder`.